How to support young oak that lost its top
Last year a piece of construction debris was blown by the wind and took off the top of our young oak tree. This year it had recovered but doesn't have a central continuation of the trunk. Branches seem to be doing well. Is there anything I can do to support the tree to have it grow healthily?



When the top branches were damaged, one of those branches would have been the apically dominant one. Having that in place prevents the tree from excessive lateral growth and works to encourage upward growth until it reaches a certain height, at which point there would be more lateral growth. Your tree will eventually produce another leader (one with apical dominance) but you may want to prune back very long lateral growths in the meantime. I can see one shoot on the left near the top, coming off a lateral branch, and it's pointing straight up - you really want a shoot closer to the centre of the tree to be the leader. Hopefully, that isn't the shoot the tree has chosen to be the leader so keep a eye on it, you may need to prune it off. You do not need to provide support for the tree, but removing some of the lateral growths (up to a third of the length) will reduce the risk from wind
damage. Do not use any pruning treatments such as paste or paint on ones, these are no longer recommended, but make sure the tool you use to cut back is clean and sharp to get clean cuts. If you are unsure or its difficult to access all the branches (can't tell how tall it is), call an arborist.

Oak Wilt is prevalent in a lot of the US, so @Joshua, if you're in the US don't prune the oak until winter or you risk having wilt spread to your tree. Winter pruning only is now the standard for oak trees in the US.

Interesting - I did not know that, thanks for the info Jurp - not a problem in the UK -yet.

Thanks, this is really good information. @Jurp another of my oak trees has bad looking leaves. Is this possibly oak wilt? The first three pictures are from one tree and the last is its neighbor. https://imgur.com/a/Al5Kgt1

A tree usually flags when it gets wilt - that is, one branch yellows/browns, then dies. If it's a black oak family species (like yours), then the tree essentially collapses and dies. There is no cure. I don't think your tree has wilt - it looks more like environmental problems.

Bamboo seems to work well to support the limbs until they are strong enough.
Bamboo

You really need to clean the top where the break was. Saw it to a clean cut without jaggies.   Otherwise this where the rot will start and penetrate into the tree.
Otherwise there is nothing to worry about.  If you don't want it to spread too much, you can prune/trim the lower branches.

Pruning paste or other forms of treating a cut are no longer recommended - they are more likely to cause an infection rather than prevent one

@Bamboo: I agree that there's no benefit in covering the cut in paste or wax, but a new clean cut might still be worth it. If the thicker top branch becomes the new leader it will be weak due to the wound extending down below it.

Normally I'd agree, but that should have been done last year when it got broken - now, in order to make  a clean cut, the first 3 or 4 (maybe more smaller ones, but certainly two thick ones) branches would need removing to get beneath the hole below the fractured area, that's quite  a lot of growth to remove. I'd probably do it were it mine, but I reckon a physically present arborist is better placed to make that choice.
